# "continuous" plotting in Pygame

Tags: python, plot, pygame

I do I plot a "continuous", moving plot in Pygame, like the plot in [this](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/run.cgi?Altruism.735.518) "NetLogo" simulation? My main difficulty is not the plotting itself (lines between points) but the process of moving the framework of the plot when the curve getting close to the edge of the box.

Thank you.

Comment: the link does not work - class not found

Comment: Press "run altruism" here: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Altruism

Comment: ok, could you explain a bit more, what you are trying to accomplish? To operate on pixels you can use pxarray

Comment: I made a simulation similar to this simulation. I want to implement in Pygame a plot that is similar to the plot in NetLogo's simulation (in the left down corner), a plot that is updated continuously while the simulation is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can make a plot similar to the one in the application in the following way:

create a surface of the size of the graph. Then create a pixel array, so you will be able to modify the graph.

```
pxarray = pygame.PixelArray (surface)
```

you can then manipulate the array like any other array:

```
pxarray[x][y] = 0xFF00FF # this will set pixel at x,y to purple
```

you can normally then normally blit the surface to the screen.

more on pixel arrays : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html

**EDIT**: Using pxarray, and transform you will have a shrinking graph if your numbers go out of range. Simply when the point is too big for the plot, you add enough rows, and use `transform.scale` to scale back to the original resolution.

Comment: Thank you but constructing the graph itself is not my difficulty. Notice what happen in the simulation when the curve getting close to the edge of the graph: the all curve "shrinks" in a way that the new data can be displayed, although the curve is getting close to the edge. How do i mimic this behavior?